# error:cannot appear in constant expression while using multimap

Tags: c++

I am writng program to get backtrace of process having multiple threads. I am using multimapping so that backtrace of each thread can be mapped to the corresponding threadid.

Here is the code:

```
     multimap<int,std::vector<strings >frames>> mt;
```

............
............

```
mt.insert(pair<int,std::vector<string>(threadid,funcname));
```

When I am compiling I am getting error
error:'threadid' cannot appear in a constant expression
error:'funcname' cannot appear in a constant expression.

Please help me in assigning the values to multimap.

Comment: Shouldn't the type of your multimap be `multimap<int, std::<vector<strings> > >` ?

Comment: Make a [testcase](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

One obvious error is that you are missing one closing angular bracket. Replace this:

```
mt.insert(pair<int,std::vector<string>(threadid,funcname));
```

with this:

```
mt.insert(pair<int,std::vector<string> >(threadid,funcname));
//                                     ^ here
```

You can simplify everything by using the `std::make_pair` function template:

```
mt.insert(std::make_pair(threadid, funcname));
```

Comment: mt.insert(std::make_pair(threadid,funcname)); is working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How to traverse this multimap?                                        I am using following method  for(multimap<int,std::vector<string>>::iterator t=mt.begin();t!=mt.end();t++)       {cout<<"first is "<<(*t).first<<"second is"<<(*t).second<<endl                      but it is giving compilation errors.

Comment: @user2380779 Youe almost there. The error is because `i->second` is an `std::vector<std::string>` and there is no `ostream& operator<<` overload for that. You could iterate over `i->second` and print every string.

Answer (score 0):

pair is templated on types which you are not specifying.

You can use

`mt.insert(std::make_pair(threaded, funcname));`

which will deduce the template parameters or alternatively you explicitly specify them (which isn't recommended):

`mt.insert(std::pair<int, std::vector<std::string>>(threadId, funcname));`

EDIT:

The reason why make_pair exists is that any constructor will be a member of the specified class and so cannot deduce its own types. make_pair is a free function and so does't have this limitation.

Comment: Do you know why these are different? Why doesn't the pair constructor deduce the arguments? And why is it a constant expression?

Comment: I have used mt.insert(std::pair<int, std::vector<std::string>>(threadId, funcname)); only....compilation is failing because of that

Comment: @Sarien `pair` is a class template, not a class with a templated constructor. You have to specify the type of a pair by providing template arguments.